# Отключение участника на время

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Пожалуйста, подскажите, каком образом реализовать отключение участника (бан) на время, например, на 5 минут? Надо ли использовать функцию `time()`?

Comment: Учите орфографию. После прочтенного желание отвечать пропадает абсолютно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте сессию

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["ban"])){
    $_SESSION["ban"] = time()+300;// 300 - это твои 5 минут
}
```

далее, при работе пользователя проверяйте

```
if(time()>=$_SESSION["ban"]){
    // контент для не забаненных
}
else{
    //контент для забаненных
}
```

Comment: 300 эт секуеды?

Comment: а как в час сутки ??

Answer (score 2):

Можно в таблице с юзерами завести поле `ban_end`, в которое при установке бана писать время его окончания. Соответственно, при проверке сессии и чтении юзерских данных смотреть: текущее время больше `ban_end`? Да - бан закончен, работаем как обычно, нет - как с забаненым. Если больше нет никаких требований, то это поле получается "скромное", ни на что больше не влияющее: ничего с ним делать не надо, только выставлять в момент выдачи бана.